# search also in taxonomy, tags and custom fields

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, custom-field, search, tags

I have found many answers separately for Taxonomy, Custom fields and Tags, most of them outdated.

But how to combine a search in:

```
- designed custom fields of a custom post
- custom taxonomy terms
- Tags
- Title (already by default)
- Content (already by default)
```

One of my custom items could be for example:

```
item 1
tag: tag1, tag2, tag3
taxonomy: tax1, tax2
custom field 1: cf1
title: composed title 1
desc: a full paragraph with many words
```

Now I would like to be able to search for :

```
"paragraph tag2 cf1 composed"
```

The solution seems incredibly complicated... is it only possible with a new SQL query (`JOIN LEFT` etc) of can I find my way with simple `$query->set()` ?

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'cjg_theme_filter' );

if (!function_exists('cjg_theme_filter')) {
    function cjg_theme_filter( $query ){

    if ( $query->is_main_query() ){
          //is_search is necessary for custom taxonomy urls
        if ( $query->get( 'tag' ) OR $query->get( 'artprim_categories' ) OR is_search() )
            $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'artprim_item' ) );

        if ( is_search() ){
            $queryString = $query->query_vars['s'];

            $queryTab = explode(' ', $queryString);

            $meta = array();
            foreach($queryTab as $queryString){
                $meta[] = array(
                    'key' => 'date',
                    'value' => $queryString,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE');
            }
            $query->set( 'meta_query',$meta );
        };        
    }

    return $query;

}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems [Relevanssi](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/relevanssi/) is a very good updated plugin

it solved my problems